Reference books to read for persecution of Jews in 16th century Europe to 20th century Europe?
I am from South Asia but I am interested in the history of other countries as well. There is a lot of media coverage  since many years on Israel- Palestine issue and a lot of anti-Semitism and hatred on the internet, even in South Asia.
What research I have done on this question: I have read about the question I am asking on the Wikipedia and I have also read 1st 2 chapters of the book Anti-Semite and Jew  by JP Sartre. The persecution of Jews in Nazi Germany was also taught in my school history class in detail and how many philosophers were anti-Semites and had a strong hatred for Jews.I have never been involved in anti-jewish hatred in real life or on the internet.

Can you please let me know of some reference books about the persecution of Jews in 16 th century to 20 th century Europe from a Jewish perspective?


Unless there is a canonical source, this question will probably be closed since requests for references rarely have an Authoritative answer.  Recommend you revise to highlight what you want to know, and rely on the site to provide references for any answers.  (thank you for documenting prior research.)

To know about the current antisemitism in Europe, I also pretended to be a person of middle east on a workplace website working in a Western Europe nation, and I wrote there that I used an antisemitic slur against an Jewish senior in the workplace. The purpose of the post was to know what would be the consequences act and what are the laws against this type of harassment.(**Now, I think that pretending to be some one else on the website was very very naive and also stupid and the people on the website told me how bad using a slur is in any setting !!

There were much better ways to ask the question without pretending to be someone else and I will never do such extremely stupid act again**). I want to again ensure you all that I have never been involved in anti-Jewish hatred in real life or on the internet.
